# SQL Server : retrieve records for a foreign key that don't have common values with another foreign key in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Id      MemberId    Field1      Field2      Data
--------------------------------------------------
1       1           12          abc         1232
2       2           13          asl         234
3       2           12          abc         2345
4       1           3           sd          sfsd
5       1           5           45r         ffgf
```

Given parameters `member1` and `member2`, I have to return all id's from `member1` that don't have the same values in `Field1` and `Field2` with `member2`.

Output example:

```
member1 = 1
member2 = 2
```

Expected output:

```
4
5
```

Because the the first record and the third record have the same values for `Field1` and `Field2`.

How to achieve this?

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Edit: I am not allowed to use cursors and temp tables (like `#tempTable`), I can use only table variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.member1 = t.member1 and
                        t2.id <> t.id and
                        (t2.field1 = t.field1 or t2.field2 = t.field2)
                  );
```

Comment: But how can this work if you don't even check if the members from tables t1 and t2 are the same with the value from the parameters?

Comment: @BudaGavril . . . I fixed the answer.  I realized that I had the logic backwards.

Comment: But I don't understand the logic of "where t2.member1 = t.member1". don't I need to check in each where clause that member id from the record matches my parameters?

Comment: Finally I've used your solution, with some mentions: I've added in both where clauses member id conditions and when I'm comparing field1 and field2, I'm using collate database_default